# How to stream a dynamically created tar archive to a browser client as a single file download?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, go, web

I am creating a server application to transfer many (could be 100+GB) files from discrete servers as a single tar archive to a browser client via a simple single file download.

Currently I settled on streaming in each file to the main server handling the web app's HTTP request, adding it to a dynamically created tar archive, and then streaming out the archive as it's created using [chunked transfer encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding).

This works nicely but has 2 main downsides:

1. No download progress indicator for the browser client/user
2. Difficult to resume a failed/interrupted download

I'm looking for advice for either different techniques to implement this app or ways to address the shortcomings above.  Some of the constraints are that since the archive is generated on the fly, the server doesn't know exactly how large the final result will be (it does have a rough idea since it is not compressed currently, it's just total(file_size + file_padding), maybe this could be determined?).  And there is limited disk space available on the server along with limited memory on server & client so the download needs to occur in a streaming fashion; ie not storing it all in-memory or on-disk on server or client before writing it out to client's disk.

I've thought about implementing this by having the browser download chunks of known size and writing it out to a file as it goes, but it's not clear to me that this can be done with today's filesystem access limitations? And also without holding the entire archive in-memory on the client side.  Aand also while presenting it as a single download to the user instead of n separate downloads.  Kept running into hiccups like this so wanted to see what y'all think

Thanks for your help :)